# Symfony3 - Serializing nested entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine

So I have a couple doctrine entities, a Subscription and a Subscriber. There are many Subscriptions to a single subscriber (manyToOne). I wrote custom normalizers for both entities, but am having trouble getting the Subscriber to show up in the Subscription once it has been normalized to JSON.

The only way I've been able to get it to work is by passing the 'Subscriber' normalizer to the 'Subscription' normailizer. It seems like I should just be able to use the SerializerAwareNormalizer Trait, or something like that, to have Symfony recursively normalize my related entities.

```
services:
acme.marketing.api.normalizer.subscription:
    class: acme\MarketingBundle\Normalizer\SubscriptionNormalizer
    arguments: ['@acme.marketing.api.normalizer.subscriber']
    public: false
    tags:
        - { name: serializer.normalizer }
acme.marketing.api.normalizer.subscriber:
    class: acme\MarketingBundle\Normalizer\SubscriberNormalizer
    public: false
    tags:
        - { name: serializer.normalizer }
```

and the normalizer...

```
<?php
namespace acme\MarketingBundle\Normalizer;

use acme\MarketingBundle\Entity\Subscription;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;

class SubscriptionNormalizer implements NormalizerInterface
{


    private $subscriberNormalizer;

    public function __construct($subscriberNormalizer)
    {
        $this->subscriberNormalizer = $subscriberNormalizer;
    }

    public function normalize($subscription, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {

        /* @var $subscription Subscription */
        $subscriber = $subscription->getSubscriber();

        return [
            "id" => $subscription->getId(),
            "subscriber" => $this->subscriberNormalizer->normalize($subscriber, $format)
        ];
    }



    public function supportsNormalization($data, $format = null)
    {
        return $data instanceof Subscription;
    }

}
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Spent a few hours on google and couldn't figure it out. Post on SO and 5 minutes later hit the right google link :(. Answer seems to be to implement NormalizerAwareInterface on the custom normalizer, and then use the NormalizerAwareTrait to get access to the normalizer for nested entities.

```
<?php
namespace acme\MarketingBundle\Normalizer;

use acme\MarketingBundle\Entity\Subscription;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerAwareTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;

class SubscriptionNormalizer implements NormalizerInterface, NormalizerAwareInterface
{

    use NormalizerAwareTrait;

    public function normalize($subscription, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {

        return [
            "id" => $subscription->getId(),
            "subscriber" => $this->normalizer->normalize($subscription->getSubscriber())
        ];
    }



    public function supportsNormalization($data, $format = null)
    {
        return $data instanceof Subscription;
    }

}
```